# Batch Script - Create user in Windows XP programmatically

Tags: windows-xp, command-line-interface, batch-file

Is there a way to create a user in Windows XP via Batch Script and even assign it administrator/limited user value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose the username is rased and password is pAsS

```
net user rased pAsS /add 
net localgroup administrators rased /add
```

here user is added under administrators group.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create a user by running `net user USERNAME PASSWORD /add` (omit the PASSWORD if you do not wish to have a password for this account, use `*` for PASSWORD to require the user to enter a password at run time).  This creates a "limited user"; if you wish to make the new user an administrator, run `net localgroup Administrators USERNAME /add` after creating the user.

Comment: +1 Rased gets the answer tag because you left out `/add` to `net localgroup Administrators USERNAME`